# AngularUI popover style change of parent element on click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap, popover

I have a pretty specific problem.  Recently I figured out how to [add a close button to an AngularUI popover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32360155/angular-ui-popover-close-button/32465263#32465263).  Originally the user had to click on the popover parent to open and to close it, so I had functionality added in that changed the style of that element on a click event.  With the addition of the close button, I want to simulate the same effect when the user clicks it.  I set up a [plnkr here](http://plnkr.co/edit/tgMIzrouUWR7mzy5pG1W?p=preview) to play with.

So far I've tried to add `ng-click="toggle(); style=!style"` in the popover template, but that didn't work.  I think that I have to access the `style` variable in the `popoverToggle` directive, but I don't know how to do that.  It might also just be possible to manipulate it in the HTML.

**Popover template**

```
<div><span ng-click="toggle()">X</span></div>
<p>content</p>
```

**popoverToggle.js**

```
angular.module('app')
    .config(function($tooltipProvider) {
        $tooltipProvider.setTriggers({'open': 'close'});
      })

      .directive('popoverToggle', function($timeout) {
        return {
          scope: true,
          link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.toggle = function() {
              $timeout(function() {
                element.triggerHandler(scope.openned ? 'close' : 'open');
                scope.openned = !scope.openned;
                scope.style = !scope.style; // doesn't do anything either
              });
            };
            return element.on('click', scope.toggle);
          }
        };
      });
```

**index.html**

```
<span ng-class="{'border-gray': style}" style="margin: 40px" ng-click="style=!style" class="red-btn">
  <span popover-placement="bottom" popover-template="'popover-template.html'"
  popover-trigger="open" popover-append-to-body="true" popover-toggle>click me</span>
</span>
```

Comment: If I click 'X' in your demo the popover closes fine. What do you want to achieve on top of that?

Comment: I want the added border to disappear when the user clicks the 'X'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is very [straightforward](http://plnkr.co/edit/tgMIzrouUWR7mzy5pG1W?p=preview), all that needs to be changed is the `style` variable.  Simply change it to `$scope.style`, like so:

**popover-template.html**

```
<div><span ng-click="toggle(); $scope.style=!$scope.style">X</span></div>
<p>content</p>
```

**index.html**

```
<span ng-class="{'border-gray': $scope.style}" style="margin: 40px" ng-click="$scope.style=!$scope.style" class="red-btn">
  <span popover-placement="bottom" popover-template="'popover-template.html'"
  popover-trigger="open" popover-append-to-body="true" popover-toggle>click me</span>
</span>
```